# Why is my unique device ID changing when I delete the app from the same iPhone in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, udid

I am getting the current device ID of an iPhone by using the below code:

```
 let deviceId: String = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!
```

...but when I delete the app from the same phone its ID is changing. Why?

The device ID has to be changed when I install the app in other devices.

How do I do that? Please help me with code.

Answer (score 4):

That's the way Apple designed it to work.  From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: thank you, but i need one deviceId for one phone... like if i delete or reinstall app in same device then it should not change. but if I install app in another phone then it can change.. how can i achieve like that.. please suggest me

Comment: A standard approach is to store a UUID in the keychain. This will be kept across app delete/re install but not if the device is erased.

Comment: @Paulw11 how to add in keychain.. please post the answer

Comment: I normally use something like [KeychainSwift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainSwift)